# Download Audio file (mp3) using nodejs from API?

Tags: node.js, audio, download, mp3

I am trying to download audio(mp3) file using nodejs from an API and when downloaded it creates a text file with extension .mp3

```html
const https = require('http'); // or 'https' for https:// URLs
const fs = require('fs');

var options = {
  method: 'POST',
  hostname: 'localhost',
  path: '/atg/audiofile',
  port: 4000,
  headers: {},
  maxRedirects: 20,
};
const path = require('path').resolve(__dirname, 'filename.mp3');
const file = fs.createWriteStream(path);

var req = https.request(options, function (res) {
  var chunks = [];

  res.on('data', function (chunk) {
    chunks.push(chunk);
  });

  res.on('end', function (chunk) {
    var body = Buffer.concat(chunks);
    // console.log(body.toString());
    res.pipe(file);
    console.log(res.headers['content-disposition']);
    file.on('finish', () => {
      file.close();
      console.log('Download Completed');
    });
  });

  res.on('error', function (error) {
    console.error(error);
  });
});

req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');

req.write(JSON.stringify({ fileCount: 1 }));

req.end();
```

I am not using any third party node library and wanted to achieve with native nodejs. Please advise.

Please note, it is a POST request.

Comment: Well, what's in the file?  An error message of some kind, from the upstream API?  Why buffer chunks like this anyway... why not pipe the res directly to the file?

Comment: Its a audio file. I am not seeing any error, but the file size is 0 bytes after res.pipe(file).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you doing a `POST` request instead of a `GET` request? Are you uploading or downloading the audio file?

This code worked a few years ago. It won't compile now. I'm trying to refactor it now. It downloads an audio file and writes the file to Firebase Storage.

```js
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        http.get(oedAudioDownloadURL, function(response) {
          response.pipe(file.createWriteStream(options))
          .on('error', function(error) {
            console.error(error);
            reject(error);
          })
          .on('finish', function() {
            console.log("Audio file written to Storage.");
            resolve("https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/" + bucket.name + "/o/" + encodeURIComponent('Audio/' + longLanguage + '/' + pronunciation + '/' + wordFileType) + "?alt=media&token=" + uuid);
          });
        });
      });
```